# Remember me cookie is not showing after browser is closed and reopened?

Tags: cookies, spring-security, spring-java-config, remember-me

I have trying to add a remember me function in my web application. This is the configurations I made with Spring.

```
..........
    .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
............

@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
            "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
    return tokenBasedservice;
}
```

Once I logged into the application and checked for the cookies I see remember-me cookie as below which is to be expired tomorrow.

[image]

But once I closed the browser and opened again I'm logged out of the application and when checking for the cookie , remember-me cookie is not shown as well.

So I want to know

1. Is this the normal behavior of remember me functionality?
2. Am I able to keep logged until the remember-me cookie expires?
3. Why do the remember-me cookie disappears when the browser is reopened?

edit: 
This is the browser settings for cookies

[image]

Firefox configuration:

[image]

Comment: I have used both chrome and firefox

Comment: Could you look into *Show Cookies...*, if your remember me Cookie exists (before and after restart of your browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off **Keep local data only until you quit your browser** to keep your cookies, see [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647):

> **Delete cookies after you close Chrome**
>
> You can let sites remember information during your browsing session, but automatically delete the cookies when you quit Chrome.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Google Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click More More and then **Settings**.
> 3. At the bottom, click **Advanced**.
> 4. Under "Privacy and security," click **Content settings**.
> 5. Click **Cookies**.
> 6. Turn on **Keep local data only until you quit your browser**.

Comment: After I did this configuration even though I checked or not the remember me check box, the browser keep me logged in until I log out

Comment: And in Firefox this does not working. I have added the configuration in the question

Comment: still having the problem

Comment: @sndu: What does *After I did this configuration even though I checked or not the remember me check box, the browser keep me logged in until I log out* mean? Do you mean after closing the browser you still logged in? You are always logged in until you log out or your session expires. But your session cookie should be removed after restart of the browser, if you checked the option.